# How to get last modified and current sysdate time difference in java

Tags: java

I have an API code which writes a token in text file. I required to check last updated time and current system. If the difference is 20 min it will generate a new token.

Problem is I am not getting difference when I use following code. How to get difference for these in minutes in an integer value?

```
java.nio.file.Path path = Paths.get("C://Users//xxx//token.txt");
attributes = Files.readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class);
System.out.println("Updated Time : " + attributes.lastModifiedTime());
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = new Date();
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
```

Comment: Where are you trying to get the difference?

Comment: If you need precision, I'd advise using `System.nanoTime` to measure.

Comment: i need difference in attributes.lastModifiedTime() and current System TIme. The generated token is valid for 20 min.

Comment: What's actually the problem - won't `(System.currentTimeMillis() - attributes.lastModifiedTime() > 1200)` give you the answer you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of getting difference is to map `FileTime` to `Instant`, which will allow to create `Duration` between two.

```
import java.time._

path = Paths.get("C://Users//xxx//token.txt");
attributes = Files.readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class);
lastModifiedTime = attributes.lastModifiedTime().toInstant()
currentTime = Instant.now()

diffInMins = Duration.between(lastModifiedTime, currentTime).toMinutes()
```

Calling `toMinutes()` on `Duration` will give back difference between given `Instant`s in minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Convert to `Instant` and compare using [`Instant.isAfter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#isAfter-java.time.Instant-) method. Do not convert to `String`, that's only useful when displaying human readable time.

```
Path path = Paths.get("C://Users//xxx//token.txt");
BasicFileAttributes attributes = Files.readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class);
Instant deadline = Instant.now().minus(20, ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
boolean itsTime = attributes.lastModifiedTime().toInstant().isAfter(deadline);
```